# expectOutputString or expectOutputRegex in PHPUnit

Tags: testing, phpunit

Hi I am using PHPUnit for my unit testing

I have a problem regarding testing output using the expectOutputString/expectOutputRegex method

Problem :

```
function test_myTest() {
    $this->expectOutputString('testxzxzxzxzxz');
    $this->expectOutputString('test');
    echo 'test';
}
```

This test pass when i generate unit test report even though the 
first expectation fails

Unlike in the assert methods, test fail if there is one assertion that fails

Example assertTrue :

```
// this test fail because the first assertTrue fails
function test_myAssert() {
  $this->assertTrue(false);
  $this->assertTrue(true);
}
```

Looks like this is a lacking functionality in PHPUnit..

Anyone have ideas or alternative way to achieve what I want when testing output?

Answer (score 10):

`expectOutputString` stores the given string to compare against the output of the whole test, but it overwrites any previously stored string. In other words, only the last call to `expectOutputString` has any effect. You must build the full output string and call `expectOutputString` just once.

```
function test_myTest() {
    $this->expectOutputString('testxzxzxzxzxz' . 'test');
    echo 'test';
}
```

The above will fail because `testxzxzxzxzxztest` does not equal the output `test`.

Comment: Got a solution : I use ob_get_contents(). By the way my output string is a json string. I use json_decode(ob_get_contents(), TRUE) to convert it to array and use assertions in each element of array.

Comment: For more complicated output tests, that's the way to go (or a wrapper class as I've done). However, simple tests can use `expectOutputString`.

Comment: ob_get_contents it is! searching for this for almost 2 hours.

Answer (score 0):

`expectOutputString` tests the whole output, so calling it multiple times does not really makes sense. However, calling `expectOutputRegex` multiple times would make sense, since a string can match multiple regular expressions. However, PHPUnit remembers only the last regular expression to match against. So subsequent calls to `expectOutputRegex` silently overwrite the expected value.

I created the following class that supports calling `expectOutputRegex` multiple times:

```php
abstract class MyTestCase {
    private array $expectedRegexes = [];

    protected function tearDown() : void {
        $this->assertExpectedRegexes();
    }

    public function expectOutputRegex(string $expectedRegex) : void {
        parent::expectOutputRegex($expectedRegex);
        $this->expectedRegexes[] = $expectedRegex;
    }

    private function assertExpectedRegexes() {
        $output = $this->getActualOutput();
        foreach ($this->expectedRegexes as $regex) {
            $this->assertMatchesRegularExpression($regex, $output);
        }
    }
}
```